# Fetch data into Ionic app from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, ionic-framework

Currently i am working on a face recognition project. The ionic function is uploading photo to php

```
fileTransfer.upload(this.myphoto, 'https://xyz.000webhostapp.com/uploadPhoto.php', options)
```

The php then executes python which recognises the face and send image data to mysql table. Is there any way I can get that data from mysql into Ionic app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert your php data into json and later fetch it in your ionic app

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$rows[] = array('data' => $r);
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```